# An application of pigeonhole principle and division algorithm

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ be an odd integer and consider $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m\in \mathbb{Z}$ fixed. If $\textbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in S_m$, that is, $\textbf{x}$ is a permutation of the set $\{1,\dots,m\}$, define $f(\textbf{x})$ by, $$f(\textbf{x})=\sum_{j=1}^m a_jx_j.$$ Show that there are $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\in S_m$ such that $m!$ divides $f(x)-f(y)$.

My attempt:

I noticed that, 
\begin{align*}
f(\textbf{x})&=a_1(x_1+\cdots+x_m)+(a_2-a_1)x_2+\cdots+(a_m-a_1)x_m\\&=\dfrac{a_1m(m+1)}{2}+(a_2-a_1)x_2+\cdots+(a_m-a_1)x_m.
\end{align*}
So, $f(x)-f(y)=(a_2-a_1)(x_2-y_2)+\cdots+(a_m-a_1)(x_m-y_m),$ for all $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}\in S_m$.

I know that I have to use the pingeonhole principle and the division algorithm. How can I do that in order to finish my proof? Thanks!

Comment: This is an old IMO problem, most likely discussed here before. Hint: Assume the contrary; thus, the values of $f$ must cover each possible residue class modulo $m!$ exactly once (by pigeonhole). Hence, the sum of all values of $f$ must be congruent to $0 + 1 + \cdots + \left(m!-1\right)$ modulo $m!$. Get a contradiction out of this by reducing modulo $2$.

Comment: Yeah! I found the solution at IMO's official page. Thanks a lot!